# use of dynamic array in android

Tags: android, database, arrays, listview, dynamic

i have recently developed a list program in android in which there is an edittext through which i enter names. these names get stored in the database and are shown in the list as well. now i want to add a button which when pressed shows a new layout with the names that i have entered in the list. the names displayed must be dynamic i.e if i enter 5 names then only 5 are shown, if i enter 10, 10 are shown and so on. i am very confused on the dynamic array thing. 
please help! 
thanks a lot!

Comment: you need to elaborate on "dynamic"

Comment: i mean to say that the new layout list must expand/deflate according to the addition or deletion of names. i dont want to keep a fixed array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be more specific. Do you mean dynamic in layout or dynamic in java? If you mean in layout you could create a container for all the names (for example a linearlayout) you would then in code create each name view (for example textview, this could be done with layoutinflation from a predefined xml resource) and add them to your container.

Comment: i mean to say that the new layout list must expand/deflate according to the addition or deletion of names. i dont want to keep a fixed array.

Comment: Use arraylist to store the names in. If you add to layout use a for loop to run through all the elements and do what I described above.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating **ArrayList of Layout**. It will help you adding and deleting the layout dynamicaly, and u won't have to give it a fix limit.